# Proof about finite fields extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I am given this problem in a Algebraic Equations class.
I need to prove the following:

> $$ \mathbb{F}_{p^n}\mid \mathbb{F}_{p^m} \text{ field extension} \Leftrightarrow m\mid n $$

I have proved the $\Rightarrow$ implication, but I am having trouble proving the other one.
This is what I have done:

$ m|n \Rightarrow \exists a \in \mathbb{N}:  n=ma $ ($a \in \mathbb{N}$ because $n,m>0$).

Besides, we know that $$\mathbb{F}_{p^n}=\{X^{p^n}-X \text{ polinomials' roots}\},\mathbb{F}_{p^m}=\{X^{p^m}-X \text{ polinomials' roots}\}. $$
Let $u\in \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$. So we have that $u^{p^m}=u$.
If we evaluate $X^{p^n}-X=X^{p^{ma}}-X$ on u:
$$u^{p^{ma}}-u $$
But I don't know how I should continue... I would be really thankful if someone helped me.

Comment: I don't understand the third implication... if $p^{m}-1|p^{n}-1$ why does $x^{p^m-1}$ divide  $x^{p^n-1}-1$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant this $m\mid n\implies p^m-1\mid p^n-1\implies x^{p^m-1}-1\mid x^{p^n-1}-1\implies x^{p^m}-x\mid x^{p^n}-x$ (corrected)

Comment: I have another question... in the first implication how to you get from $p^m|p^n$ to $p^m-1|p^n-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do have the explicit description of $\Bbb F_{p^n}$, we show that every root of $X^{p^m} - X$ is indeed a root of $X^{p^n} - X$.
To this end, let $\alpha$ be a root of the former. We have $$\alpha^{p^m} = \alpha.$$
Now raise both sides to the power $p^m$ to obtain $$\alpha^{p^{2m}} = \alpha^{p^m} = \alpha.$$
Continue repeatedly to get $$\alpha^{p^{km}} = \alpha$$
for all $k \in \Bbb N$. In particular, for $k = a = n/m$, the above is true. This gives us that $\alpha^{p^{n}} = \alpha$, as desired.